# MailCore2 - 'libetpan/libetpan.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mailcore2, mailcore

I'm currently working on integrating MailCore2 into my iOS Objective-C project. I've been going through their sample code to test and understand it better. However, I've encountered an issue where the build fails with the **error** ***'libetpan/libetpan.h' file not found.***

Despite my efforts to find a solution, I haven't been successful so far. Could anyone provide assistance with this? I'm using Xcode 15.2.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,